# Servlet doesn't work after submit button

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

New to servlets and what not. This is how my project is laid out :

```
 Projectname 
      src
        servlet.java
      web content
      META-INF
      WEB-INF 
      first.jsp
```

contents of my servlet.java : pretty much it just takes a text field from jsp

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class servlet
 */
@WebServlet("/servlet")
public class servlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public servlet() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see Servlet#destroy()
     */
    public void destroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter(); 
        try {

            String user=request.getParameter("string");
            out.println("<h2> Welcome "+user+"</h2>");
        } finally {            
            out.close();
        }
    }

}
```

The jsp :

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Input Form</title>
</head>
<body>

<form action="/servlet" method="POST">
  What's your name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="string">
  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form> 


</body>
</html>
```

and finally the web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>servlet</servlet-name>
      <jsp-file>/first.jsp</jsp-file>
 </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>servlet</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/servlet</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
```

The problem is that I can see the basic jsp, which is the form to submit a string on but nothing happens when I click submit. I don't even know where to look for errors and logs to figure out where the problem is.

Comment: I did that but still doesn't work.

Comment: Forgot to change the names when I copied here. Reverse is same s servlet.

Comment: Just did. Pretty much removed all the "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/servlet" references.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102187/discussion-between-luiz-tavares-and-tyrell-c).

Comment: your Servlet service() method is empty, so doGet() and doPost() will never be called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We had a few issues, that we've discussed at the chat and at the comments:

1. HttpServlet.service() was being overriden with an empty implementation, so doGet() and doPost() weren't being called.
2. We had a jsp on web.xml overriding the Servlet annotated mapping.

The reviewed code ended up looking something like this:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import javax.servlet.annotation.*;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class servlet
 */
@WebServlet("/servlet")
public class servlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // Overriding service() usually isn't needed. - The default implementation mostly
        // does the right thing&reg;
        super.service(request, response) 
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // Just forward the request to the jsp page on get requests
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/first.jsp").forward(request,response);
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter(); 
        try {
            String user=request.getParameter("string");
            out.println("<h2> Welcome "+user+"</h2>");
        } finally {
            // Don't close the Response - it will mess with filters
            // out.close();
            out.flush()
        }
    }
}
```